# onSubmit event handler is not being called

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to upload files in my project to the backend. I started with the frontend, and I am having trouble with the `form`, the `onSubmit` event handler is not getting called.

```
let fileInputRef = useRef(null);


const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("HEY");
};


<form
  method="POST"
  action="/"
  encType="multipart/form-data"
  onClick={() => 
  fileInputRef.current.click()}
  onSubmit={() => handleSubmit()}
>
  <label>
    <input
      ref={fileInputRef}
        onChange={() => {
           handleFileSelect();
      }}
      multiple
      className="picker-input"
      type="file"
      accept=".pdf"
     />
  </label>
</form>
```

Also, note that the `width` and `height` of the `input` element is `1px` each and I would like it to stay that way, so basically I am clicking on the `form` to open the file explorer.

Here's the css too

```
form {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  input {
     position: absolute;
     width: 1px;
     height: 1px;
     border: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try `onSubmit={handleSubmit}`. Lose the `()` and `event.preventDefault`. Does that trigger or throw error?

Comment: If it was called it would throw an error because `event` would be undefined. Not clear how you're submitting the form anyway.

Comment: It did not throw an error, it is not getting called.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added the `css` too to show, maybe the problem is there? I just feel it is there but then again I am not really able to figure it out.

Comment: where is the submit button to submit the form?

Comment: you have onClick and onSubmit, can you only use one of those?

Comment: Also you do not have a submit button, how are you trying to test that the submission works?

Comment: For `onSubmit` to be called the form has to be submitted.

Comment: I do not have  a submit button, can't I do it without the submit button? And I am trying to test the submission by having both the onClick and onSubmit event handler on the `form`.

Comment: `onSubmit` is called... when the form is submitted. If you don't submit the form `onSubmit` won't be called.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I thought it would work without the button as well. Just one last thing I want the `button` to be of the same width of the form but at the same time I want it to be not visible. so if I set the `opacity` as `0` and make the `width` as `100%`, will the `onClick` event handler still work on the form?

Comment: You probably just want to listen to change of the input.

Comment: That, and I want to submit the form too, so that the files can be uploaded to the backend.